# How to break into code when a file has been touched

Tags: c++, windows

I inherited an application using a large number of text based files for configuration.
The file's names are constructed dynamically in the software, so I can't search directly for a file name in the source code.

Is there any way to break into a program running in the debugger when it touches a particular text file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the place where the files are being open or if the dynamically created file names are assigned to some variable, create an conditional breakpoint that breaks the code execution only if the filename is matching the file that you're interested in.

Comment: String matching you mean? That depends on the tool, but even if not, you can add a line of code that does the matching and sets some integer variable based on that and than you break conditionaly on that integer value.

Comment: Even simpler: Add `if (filename=="foo.cfg") { DebugBreak(); }`

Answer (score 2):

In your debugger, set a breakpoint at the `CreateFile` (kernel32.dll) import.

**OllyDbg specific**:

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>, type in the function name and press <kbd>F2</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a breakpoint at a specific location (such as calling the function to open the file) if a variable has a specific value.